# Matrix transpose (concatenating every two index)

Tags: python, matrix, rotation, byte, transform

I have a matrix like this:

```
[99,e5],
[fc,9a],
[31,ac],
[d2,03]
```

This data are bytes from PCM audio, 16 bit, so every 2 bytes is one sample. I need to get an array like this:

```
[99,fc,31,d2],
[e5,9a,ac,03]
```

to finally interpret this array as

```
[99fc,31d2],
[e59a,ac03]
```

I've done with loops but it's very slow, and I need good performance, because it's realtime audio data.

=== EDIT ===

Maybe I explained bad

I have

```
[b'\xa5\x00', b'\xfc\x00', b'\xfb\x0b', b'\x87\x01']
```

I need to get

```
[b'\xa5\xfc', b'\xfb\x87'],
[b'\x00\x00', b'\x0b\x01']
```

Answer (score 0):

It will still be a for loop action but you could do it like this:

```
# First transpose
lst = np.array(lst).transpose()

# Now add elements
lst = [x+y for x,y in zip(lst[0::2], lst[1::2])]
```

Comment: It's not working as I want, I've edited the question with another example. Thanks in advance

Comment: I guess you could use `np.array([[l[0], l[1]] for l in lst]).transpose()` in order to split and transpose the array